# PHP HTML: mysql data as table row

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

Please help me with my problem.

I am trying to populate a table but 3 of the rows are based on my data in database(it's kinda hard to explain) sample is attach below
[image]

[image]

this is my query

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_grade WHERE instructor_id = '$inst_id' AND description = '$desc' AND remark = '$remark' AND term = '$term' ORDER BY stud_name ASC");
```

this is my html table

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" align="center" bordercolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr bgcolor="#009933">
    <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Name</td>
    <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Course</td>
    <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Prelim</td>
    <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Midterm</td>
    <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Final</td>
    <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Remark</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while($result= mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$result['stud_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"text-center\">"."</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$result['remark']."</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"text-center\">"."</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"text-center\">"."</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"text-center\">"."</td>";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

The student will be shown in the table along with his or her remark in every term if he or she failed in every term its either Prelim, Midterm, Final but can be both prelim  and midterm, midterm and final, prelim and final. etc. etc. so what is the proper query and arrangement of the table?

Comment: write the errror here ?

Comment: do you have a student id somewhere in the data or a unique identifier other than their name?

Comment: @VipinJain there is no error sir I just want to know the correct mysql query and the arrangement of the table? or table data(<td>)?

Comment: @ChrisBanks yes sir,

Comment: ok. what you want i dont understand what you say 'but can be both prelim and midterm, midterm and final, prelim and final. '

Comment: @VipinJain Okay because here in my country we have 3 term in a semester there is a posibility that a student can fail his or her class twice or the worst thrice thats the scenario sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understood what you were asking.... but here is what I have for you.
Basically you want to fetch the results and remap the data before rendering the HTML.  What I posted will not work if 2 students have the same name which is why I asked about the student id in the comments -- it'll be an exercise for you to change it to use the student id instead.

```
<?

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_grade WHERE instructor_id = '$inst_id' AND description = '$desc' AND remark = '$remark' AND term = '$term' ORDER BY stud_name ASC");

$students = array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {

    if (!isset($students[$row['stud_name']])) {
        $students[ $row['stud_name'] ] = array();
    }
    $students[ $row['stud_name'] ][ $row['term'] ] = $row['remark'];
}

?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" align="center" bordercolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr bgcolor="#009933">
    <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Name</td>
    <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Course</td>
    <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Prelim</td>
    <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Midterm</td>
    <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Final</td>
    <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Remark</td>
<?

foreach ($students as $name => $terms) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$name."</td>";
    echo "<td class=\"text-center\">?</td>";
    echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$terms['Prelim']."</td>";
    echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$terms['Midterm']."</td>";
    echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$terms['Final']."</td>";
    echo "<td class=\"text-center\">?</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Let me know if it works if I need to change anything but should get you one step closer to the result.

Comment: Hi sir I set aside this problem coz I misinterpret ehat really my problem is XD but now I have a problem similar to this please check it out -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931624/php-html-table-pivot